# how to connect SQL server with php web application using wamp server?

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

i am using **wamp server 2.5** and **php 5.5.12** and **SQL server 2014**.

i am trying to connecting a php application . but its giving me an error to connecting a database

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The MSSQL extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3
>   or later. SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from
>   Microsoft: »
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Step by Step

1. Download SQLSRV32.EXE (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server) from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
2. Choose path: C:\xampp\php\ext

[image]

3. Uncomment or Append `extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` in `php.ini`
4. Restart Apache from XAMPP Control Panel (Stop/Start)

I tested it and it works 100%

Comment: Hii @lea Tano : after fallow your steps now its giving me an error.. unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xamp\php\ext\php_mssql.dll' the specified module could not be found

Comment: I read some articles and some people complained that some `XAMPP` versions do not contain the module dlls. Can you please let me know your `XAMPP` version, so I can test it myself.

Comment: xampp-win32-5.6.3-0-VC11-installer

Comment: You were RIGHT. Thing had changed. Please follow my instructions. I downloaded `xampp win32-5.6.3` and tested it 100% Check my edited answer

Comment: I am also facing same issue.Could you please explain it for WAMP Server ?