# PDO Error: could not find driver (SQL Server connect)

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

I'm trying to connect to my azure sql server database using PDO. But my code gives an error.

> Error: could not find driver

My code:

```
$conn;
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=perslegt.database.windows.net,1433;Database=products", "serveradmin@perslegt", 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
function dbClose(){
    $conn = null;
}
```

I already allowed the ip addresses 000.000.000.000 to 255.255.255.255 in the firewall. But it gave the same error.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624704/sql-server-pdo-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score -1):

Basically, to access **Microsoft SQL Server** or **SQL Azure databases** in PHP, we need to install [the SQLSRV extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php) first. If your PHP application runs on Windows, you can find step by step installation instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960139/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-web-application-using-wamp-server/28971306#28971306) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php).

Comment: i followed the steps but i still got the same error. I tried this in wamp and xampp. followed multiple tutorials with no positive result.