# WAMP SQLServer PHP 5.6.31

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, pdo, php-5.6

I have downloaded, installed and activated "php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll" and "php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll" by moving to the ext directory of php5.6.31 and adding to php.ini the lines:

```
extension = php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll 
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

even with a non-thread-safe version the extensions still do not appear on phpinfo while they are active .. would I have forgotten something?

PS: I need the driver because I have an error "Undefined class constant PDO :: SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8"

Win 7 x64
Wamp 3.1.0
PHP 5.6.31 (version 3.2 sqlsrv)

Thank you all

[img Wamp information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X12X.png) -
[img Enable Ext PHP 5.6.31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZO31.png)

Comment: You need the Thread Safe versions and not the NTS i.e. Not Thread Safe versions for WAMPServer

Comment: Also the https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: thanks for your reply, I made the changes, the dll are activated but still not displayed in phpinfo I despair..

Comment: I have been looking for 2 days on the web but I still do not understand why the extensions are active but not display in phpinfo .. I nevertheless followed all the prerequisites, would not it not better that I pass on wamp version previous wamp 3.1?

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960139/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-web-application-using-wamp-server Just amend the directories to WAMPServer directories

Comment: Same problem ... Still not in phpinfo, thanks for your answer anyway I will try to start from 0 with another version of wamp and php

Comment: Did you install the PHP-SQLServer Drivers software? the php extension does not talk directly to the SQLSevrer database. It all goes through the SQLServer Driver layer

Comment: I'm not sure I installed Microsoft ODBC driver 11 for SQLServer that's what you're talking about? Thx for help !

Comment: Yes thats what I am talking about

Comment: i am on wamp 3.1 with apache 2.4.27 i try to send an email to localhost via a sqlserver 2008 database hosted on an IIS server but i still have this error Undefined class constant 'PDO :: SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8'
which i supose comes from the sql_srv extension missing ..

Comment: i have a error  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll' - Le module spï¿½cifiï¿½ est introuvable. same thing for php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dl
what are the Visual C ++ packages installed I think it is missing?

Comment: You are still using the `NTS` (Not Thread Safe) version of the `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` Like I said in the first comment, you must use the `TS` (Thread Safe) version with WAMPServer.

Comment: On the [WAMPServer backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) there is a tool that will check the MSVC Runtimes required. Look at the bottom of the page for a link called `Checks VC++ packages installed` There is also a link to a zip file called `Microsoft VC++ packages VC2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017 zip files` that you can download and install all the required/missing runtimes

Answer (score 0):

I Fix my problem pdo_sqlsrv display in phpinfo

- I check VC++ packages installed from link RiggsFolly
- I dl x64 php_sqlsrv for php 5.6.3 and Wamp 3.1x64 in http://robsphp.blogspot.fr/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html
- I use TS version not NTS, restart computer and it's good [img phpinfo PDO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPCgl.png)

Thx RiggsFolly & [Sqlsrv for PHP 5.6 on WAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472648/sqlsrv-for-php-5-6-on-wamp-server/46286940#46286940)

but now it's php_intl.dll' - Le module spécifié est introuvable.
and icuuc57.dll missing but i solved my problem for sql_srv in phpinfo not display ext thx !!!!

Comment: for fix problem with php_intl.dll i load file icu*.dll directly in httpconf  as LoadFile "C:\wampTEST\bin\php\php5.6.31\icudt57.dll"
LoadFile "C:\wampTEST\bin\php\php5.6.31\icuin57.dll"
LoadFile "C:\wampTEST\bin\php\php5.6.31\icuio57.dll" ... not move bin/php to apache/bin